# Permissions to functionality in mvc

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner and in my project there are various functionality like notice,gallery,slider image I want to give  rights to various users to access these functionality (if user has no permission on gallery then he can't see the functionality) through attribute.

Comment: And what about reading results from googling "mvc permissions attribute" has you confused?

Comment: You basically wrote everything what you need, just search for something like this: "mvc permissions attribute"

Comment: You can also use Roles.[see Authorize attribute without customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC I use a lot of attributes on actions to perform common work

```
[ReturnableActionFilter]
[BreadcrumbActionFilter(Text = "Invoices")]
[ClaimsAuthorize("InvoicesController", "Read")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await IndexModel_Get());
}
```

You'll notice that one of them alludes to claims. This is used with Microsoft Identity. This uses a database where all users are stored. When a user logs into the website, they authenticate against the database.

There is a tabled called AspNetUserClaims into which you add claims for each user. By default I assume that a controller has READ, CREATE, EDIT and DELETE claims - with other types added as required (e.g. ViewTradePrices - which would be a simple "Yes" as the claim)

You can then add a class to hold the authorisation code. I also add HTML helpers as well as helpers in the controller to check if a user has a specific claim. Hope this gets you started

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows use of an authorisation attribute on controllers and controller methods
    /// </summary>
    public class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private string claimType;
        private string claimValue;

        /// <summary>
        /// Authorise using a claim by type (and optional value)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">The Claim Type - Usually [Controller]_[Action]</param>
        /// <param name="value">The Claim Value, usually one of Read | Edit | Create | Delete, or some other relevant value</param>
        public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(string type, string value = "")
        {
            this.ClaimType = type;
            this.ClaimValue = value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Claim Type - Usually [Controller]_[Action]
        /// </summary>
        public string ClaimType { get => claimType; protected set => claimType = value; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Claim Value, usually one of Read | Edit | Create | Delete, or some other relevant value
        /// </summary>
        public string ClaimValue { get => claimValue; protected set => claimValue = value; }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            // assume not authorised
            bool isAuthorised = false;

            // check user exists
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User != null)
            {
                // get user by claim principle
                var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;

                if (user != null && user.HasClaim(ClaimType, ClaimValue))
                {
                    // user has a claim of the correct type
                    isAuthorised = true;
                }
            }

            if (isAuthorised)
            {
                filterContext.Result = null;
                base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }
            else
            {
                // we don't use 401 as this will cause a login loop :  base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
                // Forbidden message will be shown
                filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "You are forbidden to access this resource");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanku for your answer it will be beneficial.

Answer (score -1):

you need to put an attribute on users like 'permision' and it was a int value like 0 or 1. 0 is admin, 1 is not admin.
if u.permission == 1 then show all
if u.permission == 0 then hide some options.